# How to set a QMetalRoughMaterial with QExtrudedTextMesh

Tags: qt, qt3d

I am trying to apply a metalic material texture to a 3D extruded text mesh.

I have based my example code on this:
https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qt3d/examples/qt3d/3d-text/main.cpp.html

The example uses the `QPhongMaterial`. I naively thought I could simply
replace that material by `QMetalRoughMaterial` which I tried.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <Qt3DCore/Qt3DCore>
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DExtras>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QExtrudedTextMesh>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);

    Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow *view = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();
    view->setTitle(QStringLiteral("3D Text CPP"));
    view->defaultFrameGraph()->setClearColor(QColor("white"));

    auto *root = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();

    //Light
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *lightEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(root);
    Qt3DRender::QPointLight *light = new Qt3DRender::QPointLight(lightEntity);
    light->setColor("white");
    light->setIntensity(0.5);
    lightEntity->addComponent(light);

    //auto *textMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(root);
    auto *textMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QMetalRoughMaterial(root);

    auto *text = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(root);
    auto *textMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QExtrudedTextMesh();
    auto *textTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();

    QFont font("Arial", 32, -1, false);
    textTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(-2.45f, 2.0 * .5f, 0));
    textTransform->setScale(.8f);

    textMesh->setDepth(.25f);
    textMesh->setFont(font);
    textMesh->setText("TEST");

    //FOR PHONG MATERIAL
    //textMaterial->setDiffuse(QColor("white"));
    //textMaterial->setShininess(1.0);
    //textMaterial->setSpecular(QColor("white"));

    //FOR METAL
    textMaterial->setBaseColor(QColor("blue"));
    textMaterial->setMetalness(1.0);
    textMaterial->setRoughness(0.2);
    //textMaterial->setNormal(...)); //<-- what needs to come here?

    text->addComponent(textMaterial);
    text->addComponent(textMesh);
    text->addComponent(textTransform);

    // Camera
    float aspect = static_cast<float>(view->screen()->size().width()) / view->screen()->size().height();

    Qt3DRender::QCamera *camera = view->camera();
    camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(65.f, aspect, 0.1f, 100.f);
    camera->setPosition(QVector3D(0, 1, 3));
    camera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 1, 0));
    auto *cameraController = new Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController(root);
    cameraController->setCamera(camera);

    view->setRootEntity(root);
    view->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

With the code above, I see no text in the app window, whereas it works fine when using `QPhongMaterial`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Both materials are showing for me with Qt 5.12 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I tried on Debian with Qt 5.12 and it works indeed. On Windows, it works too, I just needed to change the `QT_OPENGL` environment variable from the default value `angle` to `desktop`. However, although the light element is the same, this texture looks much darker than the `QPhongMaterial`, and looks nothing like metalic?